# Expanding Wrap Panels ony in Width and other shenanigans

Tags: c#, wpf, autosize

I want to expand a Wrap Panel only in width also the Wrap Panel shall not draw over another Stack Panel that already exists. The Problem is probably with the standard configuration of Buttons which i added to the wrap panel also my lack of knowledge about auto sizing, so content or guides to this topic would be appreciated. The Button i add to wrap panel shall add text boxes to it, but how i said just in the width.

Edit.: is there a way to add a visual studio projekt to a post/comment?

```
{
        /// <summary>
        /// Interaktionslogik für MainWindow.xaml
        /// </summary>
        public partial class MainWindow : Window
        {
            public MainWindow()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                stackPanel1.Width = Double.NaN;
                stackPanel1.Height = Double.NaN;
                stackPanel2.Width = Double.NaN;
                stackPanel2.Height = Double.NaN;
                AddWrapPanelMaster();

            }

            Button AddButtonSlave(Button but)
            {


                but.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(this.buttClickSlave);
                return (but);
            }
            Button AddButtonMaster(Button but)
            {


                but.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(this.buttClickMaster);
                return (but);
            }

            void buttClickMaster(Object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
               TextBox txtB1 = new TextBox();
                txtB1.Text = "Text";
                txtB1.Width = 75;
                txtB1.Height = 75;
                Button s = (Button)sender;
                WrapPanel wp = (WrapPanel)s.Parent;
                wp.Children.Add(txtB1);
            }
            void buttClickSlave(Object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                Button s = (Button)sender;

                if (s.Background != Brushes.Blue && s.Background != Brushes.Red && s.Background != Brushes.Green)
                    s.Background = Brushes.Red;
                else
                    if (s.Background == Brushes.Green)
                        s.Background = Brushes.Red;
                else
                if (s.Background == Brushes.Blue)
                    s.Background = Brushes.Green;
                else
                if (s.Background == Brushes.Red)
                    s.Background = Brushes.Blue;

            }

            void AddTextBox(Button sender) {
                TextBox txtB1 = new TextBox();
                txtB1.Text = "Text";
                txtB1.Width = 75;
                txtB1.Height = 75;
                WrapPanel s = (WrapPanel)sender.Parent;
                s.Children.Add(txtB1);

                // Add the buttons to the parent WrapPanel using the Children.Add method. 

            }

            void AddWrapPanelSlave() {

                WrapPanel myWrapPanel = new WrapPanel();
                myWrapPanel.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Azure;
                myWrapPanel.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
                myWrapPanel.Width = 200;
                myWrapPanel.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                myWrapPanel.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;


                // Define 3 button elements. The last three buttons are sized at width 
                // of 75, so the forth button wraps to the next line.
                Button btn1 = new Button();
                btn1 = AddButtonSlave(btn1);
                btn1.Content = "Button 1";
                btn1.Width = 75;
                Button btn2 = new Button();
                btn2.Content = "Button 2";
                btn2.Width = 75;

                // Add the buttons to the parent WrapPanel using the Children.Add method.
                myWrapPanel.Children.Add(btn1);
                myWrapPanel.Children.Add(btn2);
                this.stackPanel1.Children.Add(myWrapPanel);
            }

            void AddWrapPanelMaster()
            {

                WrapPanel myWrapPanel = new WrapPanel();
                myWrapPanel.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Azure;
                myWrapPanel.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
                myWrapPanel.Width = 200;
                myWrapPanel.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                myWrapPanel.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;


                // Define 3 button elements. The last three buttons are sized at width 
                // of 75, so the forth button wraps to the next line.
                TextBox txtB1 = new TextBox();
                txtB1.Text = "Text";
                txtB1.Width = 75;
                txtB1.Height = 75;
                Button btn1 = new Button();
                btn1 = AddButtonMaster(btn1);
                btn1.Content = "Add";
                btn1.Width = 75;
                // Add the buttons to the parent WrapPanel using the Children.Add method.
                myWrapPanel.Children.Add(txtB1);
                myWrapPanel.Children.Add(btn1);
                this.stackPanel2.Children.Add(myWrapPanel);
            }

            private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                AddWrapPanelSlave();
                this.Show();
            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: As much as I chuckle at the word, you should probably remove "*shenanigans*" from your question title.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for as a layout scheme, but I think you may need a Grid structure for your Stack and WrapPanels to work in. If they all occupy the whole window, they will overlap.

Comment: Thanks that would solve the problem with the over laping, how do i make it now that the wraper expands only in the width and that the button is always on the right